# How to select a particular data from a datatable?

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have three select statements,

```
select 1 from tbl1;  
select 2 from tbl2; 
select 3 from tbl3;
```

and in my front end i use a `Datatable` to retrieve the value from sql.

```
 datatable dt = new datatable(); dt = obj.funcgetval();
 gridview.DataSource = dt; gridview.Databind();
```

I want to select a particular data from the datatable like in a dataset we use `ds.tables[0]`, how can we apply the same in a datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `Rows` and `Columns` to read / write particular cell of datatable.

```
dataTable.Rows[rowsIndex].Column["ColumnName"] = "SomeValue";
string strValue = dataTable.Rows[rowsIndex].Column["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

To *iterate* through dataTable

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{ 
    string name = row["name"].ToString();
    string description = row["description"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select any row then use

```
DataRow dr=dt.Rows[Rowindex];
```

If you want to get any column value then

```
object obj=dt.Rows[Rowindex][columnindex];
```

or

```
object obj=dt.Rows[Rowindex]["ColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
dt.Rows[rowindex]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want select specific cell value from Datatable,you can use..

```
dt.Rows[row index]["Column name"].TOString();
```

like if you want to select **1st** row value from column say **Name** then use

```
dt.Rows[1]["Name"].TOString();
```

if u want select particular row itself you can use `Select` with `filtercondition`.

```
 string FilterCond = ur condition;
 DataRow[] myrow = dt.Select(FilterCond);
```